# How to json decode {"prop": "b=D:\\C"} with python (single backslash problem)

Tags: python, json, escaping

According to https://jsonlint.com/ this is valid json.
Why can't python decode it?
How to decode this in python?

```
{
    "prop": "b=D:\\C"
}
```

Python code:

```
s = '{"prop": "b=D:\\C"}'
l = json.loads(s)
print(l)
```

I thought it was easy to get b=D:\C as a result.

But:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

Comment: Your string is not equivalent to the same written in file. To see, `print(s)` and `json.load` from file with your JSON pasted. To fix, use raw string, and you'll have both slashes in place (`r'{"prop": "..."}'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [raw string](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-raw-string):

```
s = r'{"prop": "b=D:\\C"}' # note the "r" before string
l = json.loads(s)
print(l)
```